# Erasing Overlapping Objects In CPP

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a method called `shape1->overlaps(shape2)` and a vector of shapes.

I have to erase all shapes which overlap within my vector of shapes. I am currently at loss on how to do that, I am unsure why this code does not work.

```
for (vector<Shape *>::iterator it = shapes->begin(); it != shapes->end();){
        for (vector<Shape *>::iterator jt = it + 1; jt != shapes->end();){
            // If the shapes are not the same
            if (*it != *jt){
                // Check if they overlap, if they do remove them.
                if ((*it)->overlaps(*jt)){
                    // Print the overlapping shapes
                    printShapeInfo(*jt);
                    jt = shapes->erase(jt);
                } else {
                    ++jt;
                }
            } else {
                ++jt;
            }

        }
        printShapeInfo(*it);
        it = shapes->erase(it);
        ++it;
    }
```

The error I get is: vector iterator not incrementable in Visual Studio during runtime.

Comment: Erasing over a vector while you're looping over the same vector is almost always doomed for failure.  Use the `remove_if / erase` idiom instead.  The reason why it's doomed is because of the incrementing of the looping iterator that has been invalidated.

Comment: I've looked into that, I am unsure how to implement it when it comes to comparison of multiple vector objects - do you have any resources I could look into it that shows some example code?

Comment: See my answer to get some ideas.   You should strive to get rid of the inner loop, and possibly both loops (which I didn't attempt in my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions:

First, for the outer loop, use regular loop index, not an iterator.

The reason is that you're changing the contents and size of the vector while you're looping.  Changing the contents means that the iterator you're using now to loop with will be invalidated.  Using a plain index is much easier in this regard.

Second, for the inner loop, get rid of it and use an algorithm function (or two) to figure out what gets erased.  So essentially, you have one loop.

Here is a version (not tested) that may mimic what you're trying to do.  Note that I had to dummy up your class to attempt to show what is happening:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
//...
class Shape
{
    public:
        bool overlaps(Shape *s) { return true; }
        bool operator==(const Shape& s) { return true; }
        bool operator!=(const Shape& s) { return false; }
};

void printShapeInfo(Shape& s) {}

void foo(std::vector<Shape*>* shapes)
{
    // use a regular index here
    for (size_t i = 0; i < shapes->size(); ++i)
    {
        // get our starting point     
        auto it = shapes->begin() + i;

        // point to the next item after the i'th item.
        auto it2 = shapes->begin() + i + 1;

        // partition the objects.  Collided ones go on the left of the partition,
        // others go to the right of the partition.
        auto div = 
              std::stable_partition(it2, shapes->end(), 
               [&](Shape* s){ return (*s != *(*it2))?s->overlaps(*it2):false;});

        // check if there is anything on left side of partition
        if ( it2 != div ) 
        {
            // for each of the collided ones, print stuff out
              std::for_each(it2, div, [&](Shape *s){ printShapeInfo(*s); });

            // we're done with them, now erase them.
              shapes->erase(it2, div);

            // also erase the iterator we collided with
              shapes->erase(it);
         }
    }
}
```

What was done?  We used [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) to move the collided elements to one side of the vector, where `div` is the dividing line between the collided and non-collided items.

This then gives us a chance to call `printShapeInfo` for each item.  Then we finally remove them from the vector using `vector::erase`.

Note that iterator invalidation errors are eliminated (hopefully) with this implementation.  The algorithm functions just "work" when given the correct parameters.  You also don't see tricky code trying to reseat the iterators.  For sequence containers, there is little reason to write loops that iterate over the container, and at the same time erase from the container.

Again, this was not tested, but you should get the gist of what was done.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for the detailed solution, I've tried to understand how it works and I am having a bit of trouble understanding, when I run my program it seems to not work as expected. It doesn't seem to be removing the shape that originally collides, so with two collisions it's printing out the information of just one of the shapes that collided and removing just that one. How would I write the code so that both shapes are eliminated (or in the case of multiple overlaps in the array per multiple shape how would I do that?)

Comment: So, basically say I have 20 shapes, say there are two shapes colliding, this solution seems to just remove the second shape that collides. How would I make it so it removes both?

Comment: @Display See my edit.  The original iterator is saved and is removed separately if we detect that it collided with any of the other items.  Note the check -- all that is done is to see if the partition yielded anything on the left side.  The bottom line is that you should understand how the algorithm's work.  Even if there is an error, I'm sure that tweaking the code here or there will get it to do what you want.

Comment: Paul, thank you so much, this is absolutely fantastic and it works perfectly. I can't thank you enough for the effort you put into answering my question! I will analyse the code in more detail now as I integrate it more into my program structure, I get the gist of what stable_partition is doing and how the iterators were running, the last spark of understanding came with modifying the structure to copy the original iterator which was something I was neglecting when modifying your pre-edit solution. Thanks again so much!

Comment: It's not clear why you suggest changing the outer loop to an index instead of an iterator.

Comment: @Display No problem.  The tricky part is really knowing what algorithm(s) to use to solve generic problems such as erasing elements that satisfy a condition.  There is also `std::remove_if`, but that wouldn't work too well due to it invalidating your items in addition to moving them to the "back" of the vector.  So `stable_partition` was used instead.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Sometimes it's easier to use indexing.  I thought it would be easier to tackle the problem from the inside out, where the inside loop was sort of obvious to remove.  I could follow up with the outside loop eliminated, time permitting.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the only problem is the `it++;` at the bottom of the outer loop.

Consider what happens when there's only one shape left in the vector.  You get to the bottom of the loop and erase that last shape.  This updates `it` to `shapes->end()`.  You can't then increment `it` again, as that would go off the end of the array.  In production code, this would be undefined behavior.  In debug code, it looks like Visual C++ is providing some detection.

Delete the `it++;` statement, and you'll always be pointing to the next shape (if any), which appears to be what you want.